# How to get notify which SMS got read from native(phone) if multiple unread SMS are present in phone(native)?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

If 3 unread SMS messages are present in native(phone), and user has read one of the SMS. How to identify which SMS got read(from native) in our application.

Currently I am using ContentObserver and onChange() method is called when user read SMS from native(phone).

I am able to get all unread SMS messages:

```
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "read = 0", null, null);
```

How to identify which SMS got read from native(phone). Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

In Nexus 4(Android 4.3) - API 18), If notification(in device status bar) for two unread SMS(belongs two different sender) in Android Native Sms Client, user clicks on that notification, onChange(context, uri) is called in my aaplication, inside it I have tried to get id of the read SMS:

```
String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
```

For above mentioned case, "inbox" as value of "id" came. But for reading any of the SMS by user from in Android Native Sms Client, onChange(context, uri) method is not invoked.

In Samsung Galaxy S3(Android 4.1.2 - API 16), onChange(context, uri) is not at all invoked in either of the case (i.e. if user read the SMS from Native or user clicks on the notification(in device status bar) for two unread SMS(belongs two different sender) in Android Native Sms Client.

(In API 16, when new SMS received in native, onChange(context, uri) is called and value of "id" is equal to the unique ID for that SMS - Tested on Nexus 4(Android 4.3))

Note: Here, "from native" means "from the device's default SMS client".

Comment: You have 3 unread sms and u have read one of them.And how to identify the last marked sms ? If is this is your question, then why cant you take the last element of the cursor of all "read" sms ? Dont know whether this would help you :( PS Try sort bye Thread_id or _id

Answer (score 3):

To determine definitely which message has changed from unread to read, you will likely have to track the state of all unread messages in your own data structure and compare during each onChange detected by your Content Observer to determine which/if any messages changed read states. You may able to improve performance by including additional projection and selection arguments in the Content Resolver queries to narrow the data set to only the fields of interest.

Hopefully, the upcoming [changes to the SMS APIs that Google is promising](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) in Android 4.4 will make the use of hidden APIs and Content Providers unnecessary for these sorts of purposes moving forward.

You may also be able to determine the SMS that was read (or at least the thread) by looking for the markAsRead debug message that is generated by the [com.android.mms.data.Conversation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/a31f51757729c398165682f3107aa17a6e03eb94/src/com/android/mms/data/Conversation.java) class used by the native Messaging app:

`D/Mms (1645): [192] markAsRead: update read/seen for thread uri: content://mms-sms/conversations/4`

However, that may not always be reliable and would not work on Android 4.1+ devices unless your app has system privileges due to the restrictions placed on the READ_LOGS permission in API Level 16.

Comment: Hi iryanmac, many thanks for the suggestion. I have followed your suggestion related to track the state of all unread messages in your own data structure and it has worked for Android version below than 4.1. Please guide me for Android 4.1+ versions (I have updated the content of the question)

Comment: Hi abhishek, glad to help. I tested the code I provided in your linked question on a GS3 running Android 4.1, and I am receiving the anticipated onChange notifications. So I would suggest verifying that your content observer service has been successfully created, registered, and started by adding appropriate debug messages. Then if you are still not receiving onChange notifications, you may need to change the URI that you are watching for changes (e.g., use content://mms-sms/conversations/ instead of content://sms/) or broaden/remove the selection criteria that you are using in your query.

Comment: Thanks i am using content://mms-sms/conversations/ instead of content://sms/. this is now working.